# How to create a new psml page?

Tags: portlet, jetspeed2

I've encountered a .psml page in a portlet app and I don't know how it was created. There exists no physical file for the .psml page. In jetspeed is it possible to create a page via portlet UI, if so how is this achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create a page in JetSpeed through the UI. To do this

1. Log in using your administrator account.
2. Click 'edit' (the little pencil icon that shows on each page)
3. You will see the Page, Folder and Layout configuration on that page.

My understanding is that .psml files are supposed to live inside the pages folder in your Jetspeed home.

Interestingly though, you say your .psml page is inside your app. I am not sure why this would be. If this is the case, perhaps the page was put there by accident?